# Received invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response

Tags: ios, socketrocket, lichess

I'm trying to connect to lichess web socket server with a very typical piece of code:

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "wss://socket.lichess.org/")!)

    self.webSocket = SRWebSocket(urlRequest: request as URLRequest!)
    self.webSocket!.delegate = self
    self.webSocket!.open()
```

But for unknown reason I receive an `Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response`:

```
    2017-02-28 16:01:06.724415 Lichess[58458:3046032] Optional(<CFHTTPMessageRef 0x100f08140(0x100f08150)> { parsed response, url = (null), status = 200 })
    2017-02-28 16:01:06.724563 Lichess[58458:3046032] Did fail with error: Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response
```

I was trying to figure out what is going wrong for a past few hours, but still have no solution. Who is familiar with this `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` and where could be an error hidden?

Comment: Hi, Alexander Perechnev
Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev hi Said. I don't remember if I found a solution since it was few years ago. It was a just-for-fun project, so I think I just stoped to work on it.